# Can´t replace this "'" for '

Tags: c#, string, replace, regexp-replace, quotation-marks

So, what I need to do replace this string **" ' "** (whitout space) for **'**, and the .Replace() is the ovios way, but when I try to do

- `txtAux = txtAux.Replace(" "'" " , "");`

the 3rd **"** didnt represent as I expected.
I try to do something like I do sometimes on .Split...

- `txtAux = txtAux.Replace(new string { " "'" "},new string {"'"});`
  Also I try to Regex, but regex im not shure to use Regular Expression.

I have this:**'"' CHARSET '"'|''' CHARSET '''**
I need this:**"CHARSET"|'CHARSET'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"` is a special character, part of the language syntax, which helps you define string literals. So any `"` is either begin or the end of the string unless it is *escaped*.

Escaping characters is a mechanism to tell that you want to use a special character just as a symbol, not the part of the language syntax.

To create a string containing `"` you escape it in a string literal with a backslash like this: `"\""`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually it work with \... Thank you very much!